# mysql combine two query with condition

Tags: mysql

I have two query

```
SELECT A FROM xxx
```

the seccond query

```
SELECT B FROM xxx
```

Before select between these two query, I want to run this third query

```
SELECT o.TYPE 
FROM outlet o
LEFT JOIN nomor_logo nl ON nl.ID = o.NOMOR_LOGO_WARALABA
WHERE nl.NOMOR_LOGO = '$nomor'"
```

if TYPE = penerima, I want to use SELECT A. If TYPE=pemberi I want to use SELECT B, if TYPE is empty, I want to use SELECT B.

The problem is, if I use SELECT B straight away without using If (and checking the TYPE), it will show "no data" page whenever no data in the SELECT B query. But when I tried to use if and checking the TYPE first, the no data page dont show. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide your database schema, sample data, and expected output.

Comment: _no data page dont show_ suggests a PHP fatal error. Always when developing and testing PHP code, at the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. But as has been suggested for the SQL, include sample rows from the tables and the query output you would want to see from those samples.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski where does it say the op is using php?

Comment: @Clint implicit in `WHERE nl.NOMOR_LOGO = '$nomor'"` and while that could be other languages, 8 years experience here with questions like this tells me it is safe to assume php.